# NDK: libc.so for x86 - Implementation of clone() function

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have spotted an issue with android ndk libc.so for x86 architecture. I cannot find implementation of clone() function. It exists for ARM and MIPS architecture. Also I have found this note:

```
Differences between Android 2.2. and Android 2.1:
...
- add clone() implementation for ARM (x86 and SH-4 not working yet).
...
```

in ndk_path/docs/system/libc/CHANGES.html

Do you know where can I find the "clone()" implementation for x86 architecture?